# How to disable the behaviour to remove the imports after commenting code in vscode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

When I try to comment any code in my react project it's removing the dependent imports and that's getting hard for me to debug. How can I disable this behavior?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance

Below is my **settings.json** for your reference. I have enabled some default auto settings as per my need which is been mentioned below JSON. let me know if I am missing something in JSON itself

```
 {
  "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
  // "gitlens.mode.active": "zen",
  "peacock.favoriteColors": [
    {
      "name": "Angular Red",
      "value": "#dd0531"
    },
    {
      "name": "Azure Blue",
      "value": "#007fff"
    },
    {
      "name": "JavaScript Yellow",
      "value": "#f9e64f"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mandalorian Blue",
      "value": "#1857a4"
    },
    {
      "name": "Node Green",
      "value": "#215732"
    },
    {
      "name": "React Blue",
      "value": "#61dafb"
    },
    {
      "name": "Something Different",
      "value": "#832561"
    },
    {
      "name": "Svelte Orange",
      "value": "#ff3d00"
    },
    {
      "name": "Vue Green",
      "value": "#42b883"
    }
  ],
  "gitlens.hovers.currentLine.over": "line",
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "yaml.schemas": {
    "file:///home/ravi/.vscode/extensions/atlassian.atlascode-2.10.1/resources/schemas/pipelines-schema.json": "bitbucket-pipelines.yml"
  },
  "bracketPairColorizer.depreciation-notice": false,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Codey's in bed by 10",
  "workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.tgz": "default"
  },
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "never",
  "editor.fontFamily": "'Cascade Code', 'Fira Code'",
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "git.confirmSync": false,
  "[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
  "files.saveConflictResolution": "overwriteFileOnDisk",
  "html.format.indentInnerHtml": true,
  "prettier.embeddedLanguageFormatting": "off",
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingTemplateStringBraces": true,
  "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterTypeAssertion": true,
  "eslint.codeActionsOnSave.mode": "problems",
  "eslint.codeActionsOnSave.rules": null
}
```

Comment: You need to share more information here. 
Since you are using vscode you are probably familiar with format and organize imports.
Could it be the case that you organize imports on save?
Check settings.json and make sure that you dont have a editor.codeActionsOnSave field
https://www.folkstalk.com/2022/09/organize-imports-on-save-vscode-with-code-examples.html

Comment: Hi @Disco, I have just enabled autoSave and also I am not organizing the imports on save. I have checked the settings.json editor.codeActionsOnSave is set to null. Will also edit the question by addting my setting.json file for the reference

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to remove this setting
`"eslint.codeActionsOnSave.mode": "problems",`

It basically say that on save eslint will try to fix all known problems, unused problems can be seen as a problem.

Comment: Initially, I tried removing that but still, that didn't work